# Is it possible in C++ to conditionally compile code if types are (not) equal?

Tags: c++, preprocessor, overloading

Currently I have a problem with code portability from 64 (back) to 32 bit. The problem is, that a method of a class is overloaded for 64 bit platforms that conflicts with another overload on 32 bit platforms.

The two methods look like this:

```
void myfunc(unsigned o);
void myfunc(size_t o);
```

On 32 bit architectures, they look identical to the compiler and throw some error.

So, the question is, is it possible to do something like this:

```
void myfunc(unsigned o);
#if typeid(unsigned) != typeid(size_t)
void myfunc(size_t o);
#endif
```

My current solution looks like this:

```
void myfunc(unsigned o);
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
void myfunc(size_t o);
#endif
```

But there is some bad feeling left, that WORDSIZE is not the best fit, because it does not necessarily mean, that the types are not the same.

OK, here is the problematic place line 705 and 706, that produce an error when compiling on 32-bit ARM.

*[ceph/src/include/buffer.h](https://github.com/ceph/ceph/blob/master/src/include/buffer.h#L705)*

Comment: If you're trying to overload for 32 and 64-bit integers, why not use `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` overloads?  The width of those won't vary depending on your platform.

Comment: I haven't tried this but I think `sizeof(unsigned) == nn` might work. Do you have anything against that? Otherwise, you could just rename `__WORDSIZE` to `__BITSIZE` or something in your current solution.

Comment: I already had the same idea, but sizeof does not include signedness :-(

Comment: You don't need it to

Comment: Changing types is not possible. I'm "porting" back a open source project from 64 to 32 bit (making it run on arm 32 again) and these are methods, widely used in the project. I con not simply change the class' method signature without breaking the whole project.

Comment: What's the difference between these two functions? Couldn't you live just with the size_t function for both?

Comment: Just look at my edit...

Comment: That overload simply casts to `unsigned` and calls the other variant. You can simply remove it.

Comment: I think it was intentionally added there, so I suppose it will break the 64 bit build.

Comment: Then I assume the answer to my (more generic) question is: It is not possible.

Comment: I kind of overlooked it while thinking about the answer, but I feel that this is actually something that the build system can take care of. It can easily check the size of types before the actual program compilation starts and can define an appropriate preprocessor flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an option using templates:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value || 
    std::is_same<T, unsigned>::value ||
    std::is_same<T, std::size_t>::value >
    advance(T o) {
        std::cout << "s" << std::endl;
        A::advance<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned>(o));
    }
};

template<>
    void A::advance(int o) = delete;

template<>
    void A::advance(unsigned o) {
        std::cout << "u" << std::endl;
    }

int main()
{
  A a;

  unsigned x;
  std::size_t y;
  int z;
  char p;

  a.advance(x);
  a.advance(y);
  //a.advance(z);
  //a.advance(p);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution and I would prefer it for my own code, because it is a clean code solution. But it would introduce too heavy refoactoring in some existing and well developed code base, that runs mostly on 64 bit machines, which do not suffer from this "bug". Nevertheless, thank's for that nice example code.

Answer (score 3):

If the underlying C standard library supports the ["Floating-point extensions part 1" (ISO/IEC TS 18661-1:2014)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/fpext1), then you have preprocessor macros available that can be used to identify the sizes of types:

```
#include<climits>
#include<cstdint>

void myfunc(unsigned o);
#if UINT_WIDTH != SIZE_WIDTH
void myfunc(size_t o);
#endif
```

This is supported e.g. by glibc. Beware that the test always fails if the macros are not defined, i.e. if the specification is not implemented, so you should probably check for that as well, i.e.

```
#if UINT_WIDTH != SIZE_WIDTH || !defined(UINT_WIDTH) || !defined(SIZE_WIDTH)
```

Without such implementation-defined macros, the preprocessor cannot be used to achieve what you want, as it doesn't actually know about C or C++ types.

Any solution at the C++ compilation level will require you to at least somewhat modify the function declarations.

I do not consider this solution particularly clean, but your current solution isn't either. Really, if as I suspect, the goal is to avoid certain implicit conversions, the method should be a template with a `static_assert` limiting the type as appropriate.

---

Edit:

The code above works as is with a current glibc and gcc, but I am not sure whether technically this is correct behavior. This is a technical specification extending C11, not C++. I don't know how or whether C++ incorporates these or if they would be considered implementation-defined extensions.

Also according to the specification the macros should only be defined if you

```
#define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__
```

before the first `#include<stdint.h>` or `#include<limits.h>`. When compiling in C mode GCC with glibc does actually require this.

Whether the specification is implemented can be checked by comparing the macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` against `201ymmL`. However GCC with glibc does not seem to set this macro and the documentation notes that support of the specification is only partial.

Probably you should at least make sure that `UINT_WIDTH` and `SIZE_WIDTH` are set before trusting the comparison made above. If they are not, e.g. because the specification is not supported is will evaluate always to `0 != 0`, i.e. `false`.

Comment: That is not a perfect solution, but much better than the "dirty fix" I used with WORDSIZE. I think it is the perfect fit to avoid a heavy refactoring.

Comment: @themole Again modified answer. It is probably important for your case to make sure that the test succeeds if the specification is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) for that:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
      void advance(unsigned o);
      std::enable_if<!std::is_same<unsigned, std::size_t>::value>::type
      advance(std::size_t o) { advance(static_cast<unsigned>(o)); }
};
```

Though, as others have already pointed out, I would ditch the `unsigned` variant and keep only the `std::size_t` variant.

Comment: This will give a hard error if the condition is not satisfied. `enable_if` only works properly during template substitution and OP doesn't seem to want to change function signatures.